# MongoDB - get max from result of avg aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection of products and these products have assessments. I need select product with the highest average of assessment. The problem is I can group products by average but I cannot group by average and select product with highest average.

To reproduce my problem follow these steps:

Insert products:

```
db.products.insert([
{
    name: "Product1",
    price: 1000,
    features: {
        feature1: 0.8,
        feature2: 23
    },
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"],
    assessments: [
        {name: "John", assessment: 3},
        {name: "Anna", assessment: 4},
        {name: "Kyle", assessment: 3.6}
    ] 
},
{
    name: "Product2",
    price: 1200,
    features: {
        feature1: 4,
        feature2: 4000,
        feature3: "SDS"
    },
    tags: ["tag1"],
    assessments: [ 
        {name: "John", assessment: 5},
        {name: "Richard", assessment: 4.8}
    ]
},
{
    name: "Product3",
    price: 450,
    features: {
        feature1: 1.3,
        feature2: 60
    },
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2"],
    assessments: [ 
        {name: "Anna", assessment: 5},
        {name: "Robert", assessment: 4},
        {name: "John", assessment: 4},
        {name: "Julia", assessment: 3}
    ]
},
{
    name: "Product4",
    price: 900,
    features: {
        feature1: 1700,
        feature2: 17
    },
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    assessments: [ 
        {name: "Monica", assessment: 3},
        {name: "Carl", assessment: 4}
    ]
}
])
```

And I want to group by avg of assessments and select product with max avg.

I do it following:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$assessments" },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$name",
            avg_assessment: {$avg: "$assessments.assessment"}
        }
    },
    { $project:
        {
            _id: 0,
            product: "$_id",
            avg_assessment: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Result of this query is:

```
{ "avg_assessment" : 3.5, "product" : "Product4" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 4, "product" : "Product3" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 4.9, "product" : "Product2" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 3.533333333333333, "product" : "Product1" }
```

Nice. Then I try to select product with highest avg using following query:

```
db.products.aggregate([
        { $unwind : "$assessments" },
        { $group: 
            {
                _id: "$name",
                avg_assessment: { $max: {$avg: "$assessments.assessment"}}
            }
        },
        { $project:
            {
                _id: 0,
                product: "$_id",
                avg_assessment: 1
            }
        }
    ])
```

But the result is the same but with rounded up values:

```
{ "avg_assessment" : 4, "product" : "Product4" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 5, "product" : "Product3" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 5, "product" : "Product2" }
{ "avg_assessment" : 4, "product" : "Product1" }
```

What's going on? Where is a problem?

Comment: As a warning, spamming comments on unrelated posts asking people to answer your question is very much frowned upon here. These comments have been deleted. Please don't do this again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. No `$unwind` needed here.

Compute `$avg` for each assessment followed by sort desc.

`$group` with `$first` to pick the assessment with highest avg value.

Add `$project` stage to limit the fields.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  { "$addFields" : {"avg_assessment":{"$avg":"$assessments.assessment" }}},
  { "$sort":{"avg_assessment":-1}},
  { "$group": 
    {
       "_id": null,
       "highest_avg_assessment": { $first:"$$ROOT"}
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning it works with assumption that `name` is unique, which is probably the case.

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$assessments" },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: "$name",
            avg_assessment: {$avg: "$assessments.assessment"}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { avg_assessment: -1 } // sort by avg_assessment descending
    },
    {
        $limit: 1 // only return one document
    }
])
```

Comment: @Veeram's solution is better than mine since it avoids the cost of the dreaded $unwind operator...